# Polynomial addition using Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomials

This is a code for polynomial addition using linked lists.

```
public class LinkedPolynomial{
    private Node first=new Node(0,0);
    private Node last=first;
    private static class Node{
        int coef;
        int exp;
        Node next;
        Node(int coef,int exp){
            this.coef=coef;
            this.exp=exp;
        }
    }
    private LinkedPolynomial(){}
    public LinkedPolynomial(int coef,int exp){
        last.next=new Node(coef,exp);
        last=last.next;
    }
    //return c=a+b
    public LinkedPolynomial plus(LinkedPolynomial b){
        LinkedPolynomial a = this;
        LinkedPolynomial c = new LinkedPolynomial();
        Node x=a.first.next;
        Node y=b.first.next;
        while(x!=null || y!=null){
            Node t=null;
            if(x==null){
                t=new Node(y.coef,y.exp);
                y=y.next;
            }
            else if(y==null){
                t=new Node(x.coef,x.exp);
                x=x.next;
            }
            else if(x.exp>y.exp){
                t=new Node(x.coef,x.exp);
                x=x.next;
            }
            else if {
                t=new Node(y.coef,y.exp);
                y=y.next;
            }
            else{
                int coef=x.coef+y.coef;
                int exp=x.exp;
                x=x.next;
                y=y.next;
                if(coef==0)
                    continue;
                t=new Node(coef,exp);
            }
            c.last.next=t;
            c.last=c.last.next;

        }
        return c;

    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
        LinkedPolynomial zero=new LinkedPolynomial(0,0);
        LinkedPolynomial p1=new LinkedPolynomial(4,3);
    }
}
```

In the method `plus()` can someone please explain to me what is done with

```
LinkedPolynomial a = this;
LinkedPolynomial c = new LinkedPolynomial();
Node x=a.first.next;
Node y=b.first.next;
```

What is  `a.first.next;`

What is `LinkedPolynomial`. Is it a node? Does every `LinkedPolynomial` has a first and last?

Can someone please explain these to me.

Comment: Is it intentional to have both LinkedPlynomial and LinkedPolynomial? I'm not clear on if you're intending two different classes or it's a bad retype job.

Comment: It's almost certainly a typo.

Comment: @sam_rox, just look at the LinkedPolynomial class definition, it's really straight forward. It's meant to contain a polynomial like "x^2 + 2x + 3", with each node containing a different term.

Comment: So the four lines you posted starts off by grabbing the first term of the two polynomials you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedPolynomial a = this;
LinkedPolynomial c = new LinkedPolynomial();
```

a and c refer to `LinkedPolynomial` objects, NOT `LinkedLists`. They encapsulate the list nodes.

```
Node x=a.first.next;
Node y=b.first.next;
```

`a.first.next` is a node!

The `LinkedPolynomial` class contains fields that point to Nodes. This is known as encapsulation, and is a good programming practice, so outside code cannot tamper with the nodes directly, corrupting your `LinkedPolynomials`.

Since a is a `LinkedPolynomial`, `a.first` is a Node (with `coef = 0` and `exp = 0`, to be exact). Look at Line 2. a.first.next is also a Node. Line 7 says that each Node holds a pointer to its next Node.

Each `LinkedPolynomial` does, indeed, have a first and a last. Look at the `LinkedPolynomial` constructor. To make a `LinkedPolynomial`, it already has a first and last, and the constructor can change the last if it wants.

Comment: :If the polynomials are as `LinkedPolynomial p1   = new LinkedPolynomial(4, 3);
        LinkedPolynomial p2   = new LinkedPolynomial(3, 2);
        LinkedPolynomial p3   = new LinkedPolynomial(1, 0);
        LinkedPolynomial p4   = new LinkedPolynomial(2, 1);
        LinkedPolynomial p    = p1.plus(p2).plus(p3).plus(p4);   // 4x^3 + 3x^2 + 1

        LinkedPolynomial q1   = new LinkedPolynomial(3, 2);
        LinkedPolynomial q2   = new LinkedPolynomial(5, 0);
        LinkedPolynomial q    = q1.plus(q2);                     ` after ` p1.plus(p2)`does t has coefficient 4 and exponent 3

Comment: Then with `p1.plus(p2).plus(p3)` x points to t and y points to p3 right?Then the condition that would be executed is  `if(x.exp>y.exp)`.Then again t has coefficient 4 and exponent 3 .What's wrong with the way I am going

Answer (score 0):

1. `LinkedPolynomial a = this;` 
   Means it is referring to the current object. So for example if you have

   `LinkedPolynomial zero=new LinkedPolynomial(0,0);
    LinkedPolynomial p1=new LinkedPolynomial(4,3);`

zero.plus(p1). `this` would refer to zero object.

2.`LinkedPolynomial c = new LinkedPolynomial();` This is being created to store the value of a+b.

3.According to the code every LinkedPolynomial contains two nodes `first` and `last`. So when you do `a.first`, it is accessing the first node and when you do `next` after that, it will access node next to first.